# ASP.NET Web API change request URI (Redirect to another method)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET project in which API versioning has been implemented via URL versioning. eg:

```
api/v1/Resource
api/v2/Resource
```

Now the requirement is that if a user requests a resource which is not available in that version, then it should fallback to previous version. Let's say user wants to access `api/v2/SomeResource` but the same is not available, then request should be forwarded to `api/v1/SomeResource`.

Can we intercept every incoming request and change the RequestURI before Route is decided?

I have tried using a **DelegatingHandler** to change the Request URI, but seems like route is decided before DelegatingHandler is executed.

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync
    (HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(getNewURI(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri), UriKind.Absolute);
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Is there anyway we can change the ReqestURI before Routing is finalized by Web API or any other way to accomplish this kind of redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know ahead of time that the route no longer exists (you would have to if you knew which route you wanted to redirect to) then you could just add multiple routes to the same method. Otherwise you would have to call the route to see if it existed, if it gave a 404 you would then have to attempt again with the next one and so on.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/v2/resource")]
[HttpGet, Route("api/v1/resource")]
public IHttpActionResult YourMethod()
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, adding multiple routes would work, but it would get pretty big as new API versions come into picture over the time "v3,v4......"

Comment: The `RouteAttribute` take a url template as a parameter so you may be able to use `[Route("api/{version}/resource")]`.

Comment: But that would find multiple controller methods at the same URL and throw an error

Comment: Only if it existed somewhere else. You would need to know which resources have been moved. To know you would need to call another endpoint when one wasn't found but at another version would imply that you know which one is missing and which one it needs to be routed to.

Comment: @StephenBrickner
My previous response was to @R Day, as using "api/{version}/resource" would conflict with "api/v2/resource" or "api/v3/resource" if that comes into picture in future